# Alternative for BehaviorRelay in Swift Combine

Tags: rx-swift, combine

As part of moving from RX to Combine. What exactly works like "BehaviorRelay" of RxRelay in Swift Combine?

Comment: You probably want to use `CurrentValueSubject`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in this [Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/CombineCommunity/rxswift-to-combine-cheatsheet), an RxSwift BehaviorSubject is the same as the Combine CurrentValueSubject. A BehaviorRelay is a simple wrapper around a BehaviorSubject and could easily be recreated in Combine, but doesn't exist natively.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the Cheatsheet. It's very useful.